# Defining Child Tables and getting records from them

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am new to SQL. I am looking at creating a database where a value in one table is a pointer to another 'whole' table *(not just a value in the other table ... but the table itself)*. How can one achieve this and how can one write an SQL statement to access data in the child table?  I'll illustrate with the following tables

**Project:**

```
ID   Name   Site              Client          Progress
------------------------------------------------------
1    Bronx  99-Beans Street   Mr.Smith         **1 
2    Mandy  4-Apt Clinton     Mrs. Cross       **2
3    Ani    7-Magbo,Jos, NG   FRN, 9ja         **3
```

**Bronx:**

```
Task Description             Start        Finished   Handler
-------------------------------------------------------------
1    Remove Top-Soil         07:50:33     12:10:05   Jack
2    Break Ground            13:00:20     15:33:52   Grader
3    Spray Fertilizer        15:55:30     17:15:23   Suzie
```

Notice that the second Table takes its name from the Name Value of Project @ id=1. The Id could still serve this purpose, in which case, the table would be titled **'1'** ... *which is rather odd*, but at least this explains the kind of relationship the tables should have. Deleting a record in the **'Project'** Table should also delete the associated **Progress table**(bearing the name of the record)*.  How can one create & Query tables with this relationship in SQL?

Comment: Why exactly do you need a whole new table for each row in 'Projects'? This can be done but imo it's not how relational databases should be used. Maybe you should consider using a key->value or an object database?

Comment: @pablochan: Could you throw more light on 'key-value or object databases'?

Comment: @twohot Key-value databases work kind of like hashmaps (or dictionaries if you prefer). There is no schema. You store objects(documents) that consist of arbitrary attributes (a name/key->value pair). Check out CouchDB or MongoDB (there are a lot more but these are fairly popular).

Comment: @pablochan: Thanks for that information.  MongoDB comes close but recording row headers along with each value doesn't sound cool.

Comment: @twohot: Than modify your design and use sqlite. Don't use separate tables for tasks. Make one 'Tasks' table and connect it to the 'Projects' table via a foreign key (a column in the 'Tasks' table that has the project id).

Answer (score 0):

In the project table you have to make sure that not only is the ID field unique but the Name field as well. Since you want to create tables in the database using the name field this would pose an issue if you had duplicates. Next I would make a call to the projects table from my program, read the table name, then pass that name to another query for the specific project. In the case where the specific table, Bronx, for instance is removed from the project table you could write a trigger in the project table that would say delete the project specific table listed in the Row column. Bottom line is only part of what you need done can occur in SQL while the rest should be managed in your program.

Comment: Actually I'm accessing these tables from a Python3 script. I see you point. Thanks.